# OOP: retrieve 'fathers' attributes from the 'child' object

Tags: php, oop, class, inheritance

here i am again ;)

My problem atm is with nested php classes, i have, for example, a class like this one:

```
class Father{
    public $father_id;
    public $name;
    public $job;
    public $sons;
    public function __construct($id, $name, $job){
        $this->father_id = $id;
        $this->name = $name;
        $this->job = $job;
        $this->sons = array();
    }

    public function AddSon($son_id, $son_name, $son_age){
        $sonHandler = new Son($son_id, $son_name, $son_age);
        $this->sons[] = $sonHandler;
        return $sonHandler;
    }

    public function ChangeJob($newJob){
        $this->job = $newJob;
    }
}

class Son{
    public $son_id;
    public $son_name;
    public $son_age;
    public function __construct($son_id, $son_name, $son_age){
        $this->son_id = $son_id;
        $this->son_name = $son_name;
        $this->son_age = $son_age;
    }
    public function GetFatherJob(){
        //how can i retrieve the $daddy->job value??
    }
}
```

that's it, a useless class to explain my problem.
What im trying to do is:

```
$daddy = new Father('1', 'Foo', 'Bar');
//then, add as many sons as i need:
$first_son = $daddy->AddSon('2', 'John', '13');
$second_son = $daddy->AddSon('3', 'Rambo', '18');
//and i can get here with no trouble. but now, lets say i need
//to retrieve the daddy's job referencing any of his sons... how?
echo $first_son->GetFatherJob(); //?
```

So, every son must be indipendent from each other but inherits the attributes and values from the father one..

I've tryed with inheritance:

```
class Son extends Father{
[....]
```

But i'll have to declare the father attributes every time i add a new son..otherwise father's attributes will be *null*

Any help?

Comment: as a side comment: letting Son extend Father would meen that conceptually, your son IS A father, which is in general not true. What would be reasonable though is creating a parent class Person with the common attributes with Father and Son both inheriting from it.

Comment: I have to agree with HerdplanttenToni. Applying the object oriented principles will lead to using a Person class which is a type which can be a son or father. Using the Father class and Son class lead to relationship which is a data model and not a object model.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't unless you tell the sons who their father is. This could be done by adding a setFather() method to the son and calling in the addSon() method of the father.

eg.

```
class Son {
    protected $_father;
    // ...
    public function setFather($father) {
        $this->_father = $father;
    }

    public function getFather() {
        return $this->_father;
    }
}

class Father {
    // ...
    public function AddSon($son_id, $son_name, $son_age){
        $sonHandler = new Son($son_id, $son_name, $son_age);
        $sonHandler->setFather($this);
        $this->sons[] = $sonHandler;
        return $sonHandler;
    }
}
```

As a side note, I wouldn't create the son within the AddSon method, I would have that method take an already created son as its parameter.

Comment: YOu could even use a PHP magic method so that $son->job() automatically went and got the job from the father; but you'd still have had to tell the son who the father was.

Comment: Brenton solution works good, but please, exmplain even the 'magic method'

Comment: It wouldn't have to be magic, it'd just be a method in the son that looked like:

public function getFatherJob() {
    return $this->getFather()->job;
}

I'd personally rather chain the methods in most cases, but up to you.